# Shared Pointer In Manager class corrupted/incorrect?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

Apologies if this is obvious, and I'll try and provide a minimal example as I've been banging my head over this for the last hour and I'm certain it's something simple.

I have the following:

```
class Table { /* implementation superfluous */ };
typedef boost::shared_ptr<Table> TablePtr;
```

Later, in a database class:

```
class Database{
    typedef std::map<std::wstring, TablePtr> table_map_type;
    table_map_type tableCache_;
};
```

And I define an operator to obtain a table:

```
TablePtr Database::operator[](const std::wstring& name) {
    table_map_type::iterator it(tableCache_.find(name));
    if(it != tableCache_.end())
        return it->second;

    // not found, create
    TablePtr ret(new Table());
    tableCache_[name] = ret;
    return ret;
};
```

Now what is happening is, in my first call to this it's fine.  Nothing is found with a given table name, it's created - placed in the map, and returned within the shared pointer.

The issue occurs later on, when I come back to the same instance and look for the same name.  It correctly finds it, and returns on `return it->second`.  However, the next immediate call on that object flies off in to demons and noses with an object that was not the one created.

I am certain I am missing something obvious.  Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

As my minimal code example worked, I'm going to have to dig even deeper.  It appears that, even the first insert doesn't work properly.  Within the `operator[]` function described above, the `TablePtr` constructed holds a valid table object within it (because the internal name shows as `L"_contract"`.  I did a simple test line:

```
db::TablePtr first((*db)[L"_contract"]);
```

Within that function, the tables name is `_contract`.  Examining `first` in the debugger, shows a table name of `L""`.  Something is going awry somewhere.  Trying to get more code to reproduce it outside of the actual classes.

Comment: Yup, a test-case would be useful.

Comment: `std::map::operator[]` will already insert an element if it doesn't exist. (It just won't do `new Table()` for you.)

Comment: @sftrabbit: Indeed.  I can't quite see how that affects this, though.  Because the OP is immediately assigning the correct thing to that element.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Yeah, I was under the impression that it also returned a pair, where the second element was whether the item existed beforehand or not. That could have been used. But it appears I'm thinking about something else. =/ Edit: Aha, it's `std::map::insert`.

Comment: @sftrabbit: I think you're thinking about `insert` ;)

Comment: My Minimal, simplest test-case worked just fine, so I am extending it out to further mimic the situation.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth It appears that the shared pointer returned after the *first* insert suffers from the same issue.

Comment: @Moo-Juice: I must admit I have no idea what's going on, but couldn't it be that you are working with an invalid `db` pointer in the first place?

Comment: @AndyProwl, Yes.  In my second test, I both `db()` calls are the same pointer.  I even did some other tests to check that address versus a weak reference held in a shared pointer (they were the same).

Comment: @Moo-Juice: Really, no idea. If you could post an SSCCE, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many apologies to everyone who kindly commented.  As usual, it's what happens when you've been staring at the screen for too long (time for a break?).  It turns out that I was storing a reference to the table name within the table, rather than copying it over.  This meant that when the (L"_contract") went outside of scope (out of sequence?), it was effectively dead - hence the latter problems.

Thanks to all who looked at the question bemused.